# Dipole Moment in P4O8 molecule

Tags: bond, dipole

[image: P4O8 Molecule Structure]

So from the structure, which seems to be quite symmetrical, according to me the dipole moment should be zero.

Comment: It's difficult to comment on dipole moments of such extended oxides as they are usually isolated in the crystal phase and will require QC calculations. However even on a basic observational basis, we can perhaps comment that not all the P-O bond lengths are same. Also, you called P4O8 "symmetric", but a cursory glance at a 3-D model will show that the two P=O vectors don't exactly cancel each other. So qualitatively we may suspect this to have a dipole moment. But proper bonding analysis and confirmation will require computation.

Comment: You may check the conformer here: https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Tetraphosphorus-octoxide#section=3D-Conformer

Comment: Try this one [link.springer.com](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00894-012-1633-7)  but paywalled.  sci-hub.se may be blocked in some countries.

Comment: @Poutnik Ok i will check it out..

Comment: @YusufHasan yes the 3d model shows the P=O aren't symmetric, yes I understood, that there is no such symmetry...Thank you!

Comment: Try to work out the point group, its possible it is C2v .

Comment: http://csj.cumhuriyet.edu.tr/tr/download/article-file/1055622 says P4O8 is C2V, but it's a computational study so I'd like to study the method more carefully before I believe it, on first glance the basis set doesn't look that big. (note I am a computationalist). https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jcp/article/5/8/626/209772/The-Molecular-Structure-of-P4O6-P4O8-P4O10-and is an experimental study from 1937 (!) which says they can't tell.

Answer (score 5):

This is an example of the danger of reading too much into two-dimensional paper representations of three-dimensional molecules.

Imagine the two pendant oxygen atoms were not there and you had just $\ce{P4O6}$. The phosphorus atoms would then be equivalent. So to make  $\ce{P4O8}$, instead of putting the two additional oxygen atoms on top and bottom you might have put one on top and one on the right. Now the molecule looks (di)polar.

To resolve this paradox, you must use the third dimension properly. In the $\ce{P4O6}$ core each phosphorus atom is the vertex of a polyhedron whose edges lie along the $\ce{P–O–P}$ linkages. Thus four vertices and six edges, meaning a tetrahedron (not a square). With a tetrahedron the two additional oxygen atoms are not on opposite vertices because a tetrahedron does not have any such pair of vertices, so those bond polarities do not cancel and $\ce{P4O8}$ ends up having a nonzero dipole moment.